# getting individual atrributes while selecting a class with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, attr

I'm new to javascript and JQuery, and I'm working in a small project with JSP.

I create a grid dynamically with JSP and I added some buttons wich class is "select" and in the alt attribute I set the current row index. That works perfectly, I'm trying to set the onclick dynamically. This is my code

```
$('.select').click(function (){
   alert($('.select').attr('alt'));
}
```

I want to each button to show its own index, but that code shows just the first index in each button. I've searched how to do it, but nothing comes out.

Is there a chance to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line as:

```
alert($(this).attr('alt'));
```

Answer (score 3):

When jQuery calls your event handler it sets `this` to be the DOM element in question, so try this:

```
$('.select').click(function (){
   alert($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

If you need to access DOM element properties you can then get them directly, e.g.:

```
alert( this.id );
this.value = "test";
```

If you need to use jQuery methods on the element you need to pass it to the jQuery function first, e.g.:

```
$(this).hide();
$(this).css("color","red").slideDown();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.select').click(function (){
   alert($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

Change

```
alert($('.select').attr('alt'));
```

by

```
alert($(this).attr('alt'));
```

Now you select the attr alt of the button lauch the event.

Comment: You could make your answer clearer by specifying which $('.select') should be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you're looking for but...

```
$('.select').click(function() {
    $('.select').each(function() { 
        $(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('alt'));
    });
});
```

This'll have every button "show" the value stored within their alt attribute when you click one button.

By the way, if you're using 1 button per row, you'd probably better go with [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/).